What does an "entry" refer to in a Hashmap? Does it mean the quantity of filled buckets, or the overall quantity of keys?
I am following along with The Odin Project.
They state "The product of these two numbers (load factor and current capacity) gives us a number, and we know it’s time to grow when there are more entries in the hash map than that number. For example, if there are 16 buckets, and the load factor is 0.8, then we need to grow the buckets when there are more than 16 * 0.8 = 12.8 entries - which happens on the 13th entry."
Knowing this, it inclines me to believe that an entry refers to a bucket, however in the following lesson they have you implement a Hashmap. There is some conflicting information here.
For testing they say to populate an instance with these values which would set the number of entries to 12. With the hash function they provided though, some of these end up in the same bucket which is why I would like to know what an entry refers to.
 const test = new HashMap() // or HashMap() if using a factory

 test.set('apple', 'red')
 test.set('banana', 'yellow')
 test.set('carrot', 'orange')
 test.set('dog', 'brown')
 test.set('elephant', 'gray')
 test.set('frog', 'green')
 test.set('grape', 'purple')
 test.set('hat', 'black')
 test.set('ice cream', 'white')
 test.set('jacket', 'blue')
 test.set('kite', 'pink')
 test.set('lion', 'golden')

I tried tracking the number of entries by incrementing filledBucketCount by one anytime a new linked list is initialized at an index in the underlying array. I expect when I populate my hashmap with the values above, and then add one more key to the hashmap it will resize itself as the capacity * threshold is smaller than the filled bucket count. It isn't though and I believe it's due to how I am incrementing the filledBucketCount.

By "entry" they mean a key/value pair. Eg, the mapping from 'apple' to 'red' is an entry. If you'd like some help with why it didn't grow when you expected it to, please show how HashMap is implemented or imported, and how you are identifying when it grows. You mentioned some stuff like filledBucketCount and an "underlying array", but without code we don't know what those are.

This actually answers my question. Perhaps I was too verbose. I was only incrementing filledBucketCount when I initialized a new linked list at an index within the array, not whenever I added a key/value pair.


TL;DR as this got quite long and detailed: As you are using a linked list implementation, the number of key/value pairs added may be higher than the number of entries without the need to expand the size of the hash table.

The main goal of hashing as used in data structures like HashMaps is to store multiple records and be able to retrieve them in linear time (best case Θ(1), worst case O(n)).
The concept of a Hash Map also relies on using a hashing function to turn a key K into a hash value which defines where the value will be stored. This hash value does not need to be unique, multiple keys can have the same hash value.
How you define what you call what realistically depends on who is teaching it.
So let's go over some of the definitions in this course and relate them to ones from this course which is closer to how a university would explain this to explain the concept a bit better.
Buckets
The course uses Buckets to refer to positions in an array. Other courses may refer to this as T, the hash table of size m.
A hash table size of m=16 means you have 16 buckets and your hashing function can store 16 distinct values or references to linked lists.
Keys
Consider a key to be the value you want to actually search by, in your case 'apple', etc. The goal of the HashMap should be to provide you with 'red' when you search for 'apple' in linear time.
Hashing function
The hashing function will take a key and "map" it to a Bucket. A typical hashing function for numerical keys would be h(k)=k mod m.
Note this does not have to be unique, it is perfectly normal that two different keys may end up in the same bucket (in the above function for e.g. m=3 you would have k=6 and k=9 both end up with a value of 0).
Entries in the Hash Table
Here is where the "Bucket" analogy can lead you astray - an Entry in the Hash Table is the water in a filled bucket.
If we don't use buckets to understand this, an entry is any key/value pair currently stored in the table (the course linked above considers this a record).
Your hash table will always have n entries (or linked lists) stored.
How does this tie together?
First, let's recap our variables and what they mean:

m: Size of the Hash Table, regardless of how much is stored in it. This is your amount of buckets.
k: A key to identify a value by, here 'apple', etc.
h(k): A key k's hash function. The same key will always have the same hash, multiple different keys may have the same one as well.
n: The number of entries currently stored in your hash table

Now, let's simulate what happens when adding the values from your question:
(We will use the improved stringToNumber function from the course you linked)

Creating the Hash Table:
We initialize the empty Hash Table with 16 Buckets (or m=16)




Index
Key
Value




0




1




...




15





(Further tables will omit empty lines for brevity, there will always be 16 indices though.)

Insert test.set('apple', 'red'): stringToNumber('apple') % 16 = 10




Index
Key
Value




10
apple
red




Repeat this for values up to grape:




Index
Key
Value




1
elephant
gray


3
carrot
orange


4
frog
green


5
banana
yellow


10
apple
red


11
grape
purple


12
dog
brown




Now when we try adding hat, which has its hash function result in 11, we notice index 11 is already taken. What now?

Handling collisions
We now have the above table and want to insert hat though we cannot insert it where it should go (index 11) as that location is taken. How you solve this is up to your implementation, some ways to deal with this are:

Open addressing: Add another parameter to the hash function to find the key by (See the linked course slides for more about that)
Other open hashing methods (Brent, etc.): Put it in the next bucket, etc.
Separate chaining: Use a linked list to store more than one value per bucket.

As your course appears to want you to use separate chaining I will go into some more detail about it: Instead of storing just the one object you will also point by reference to the first overflow entry from your table:



Index
Key
Value
Overflow link




1
elephant
gray



3
carrot
orange



4
frog
green



5
banana
yellow



10
apple
red



11
grape
purple
0


12
dog
brown




Your overflow entries:



Index
Key
Value
Overflow link




0
hat
brown




You are technically not storing key-value pairs in the buckets but a pointer to the first item of a linked list that can reference infinitely many items.
Relating back to Buckets
So now we've used a linked list to reference the next item (hat) from bucket 11.
We now have 7 buckets used (n=7) but are storing 8 values in total. How does this relate to growing the hash table?
It really doesn't. For the sake of calculating the current load α, we use α=n/m. Even though we technically have 8 key/value pairs we can retrieve by iterating through the linked list entries, we have only still used up 7 lines in the hash table (=we have used 7 buckets). It just happens to be that there are links to more values in each bucket (linked lists). As such, our current load α is 7/16=0.43.
In summary, your filledBucketCount variable (which is n in my explanation) is likely correct. It should only increase once a new heading of a linked list is added to the hash table, not just once there are more than 12 calls to test.set.
Except...
If we want to slightly change the way we calculate n to use the total number of key-value pairs inserted instead of the number of entries in the hash map used we can get the result you are expecting. This will mean your hash map will grow larger than expected (and earlier) and actually makes sense if your hashing function is often returning the same hash for multiple keys (changing the size by optimally a prime number can cause all addresses to change and be re-distributed). This is a bit of a special case when you use chaining.
Basically, you can consider entries to be the number of keys stored when using chaining to have your hash map grow earlier.

Thanks for the super detailed answer! This makes sense and lines up with what I thought as well.
Where I am having the mental disconnect is that they state after populating the Hashmap with the values discussed above, it SHOULD be over the threshold value (where this is equivalent to capacity * loadFactor or 16 * .75), yet when I do so only ten buckets are filled. I've created a replit with my code if you are willing to take a look. Maybe it's a logic error on my end. I am aware my resize() method is currently ncorrect.

Looking at it this is honestly how I would have implemented it as well - the load factor after inserting all the items is 0.625 when only calculating the used buckets while when incrementing it for each assigned item (no matter where it goes) it is 0.75 (and closer to what you're expecting). While I just know the way I outlined in my answer there may actually be merit in using the count of key-value pairs instead of the number of filled "buckets" if you expect your hash function to be inadequate as resizing will cause items to be split up in other buckets even if they have the same hashes.

Alright. Thank you!
